# Want to default 'show bounds rectangles' checked on in Interface Builder

Tags: ios4, xcode4, interface-builder

I'd prefer to have the option in the Editor, Canvas menu default to always have the "show bounds rectangles" option checked (on) but I haven't found a way in Xcode to set this stays on as a preference. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: In case anyone cares, this setting now appears to stay "stuck" on once set with Xcode 4.3.1 for which at least I am happy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone cares, this setting now appears to stay "stuck" on once set with Xcode 4.3.1 for which at least I am happy :-)